# Is it possible to locate the position of a specific block in Minecraft Java

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a datapack and I want to replace how diamonds and emeralds function by modifying their generation behavior. But I don't know if this is A : possible and B : worth my time looking in to. I did some research but could not find anything that was up-to-date with or answered when 1.18.x was around. I was told [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397562/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-ore-and-add-it-to-world-generation-with-a-data) in the comments that there was a command called `/locateblock` but I couldn't find anything on the wiki about the command or anything like it. So I am lead to believe that the command doesn't exist. If this is possible via Spigot or Fabric/Forge (As long as it is server-side) I would be willing to use a plugin/mod but I would like to avoid doing so.

If anyone is interested in or needs to know why I want to do this, I am extending on my question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397562/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-ore-and-add-it-to-world-generation-with-a-data) to get closer to adding custom ores and gemstones without (hopefully) mods/external APIs.

Comment: Sorry that locateblock command does not exist, my bad

Comment: No harm was done @DialFrost. But I would ask that you could try to either edit or remove your comment so you don't confuse anyone else who might be attempting to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone in the future ends up on this post, I have found a "solution".

From what I have learned, it is not possible or at the very least not easy to remove ores from world gen.

One method is recreating/adding biomes and modifying ore distribution in these biomes. The second method is replacing existing ores with a stone texture and replacing them with your own custom ores. [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397562/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-ore-and-add-it-to-world-generation-with-a-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) post I made has a fantastic answer covering how to add custom ores to world gen (it *is* archaic and a little slow) or you could figure out something using custom structures.